# Annotation: how to get the actual object?

Tags: java, list, object, input, annotations

Extract form main-Class:

```
Client k = getClient();
Truster kg = new Truster();
boolean ok = false;

while (!ok) {
    System.out.print("\n name: ");
    //io: is a class for my input from Keyboard

    kg.setName(io.readString()); // <--need the input from here

    //argu_vali is my ValidationClass
    if (argu_vali.analyse(k, "mylist") == 0) {
        ok = true;
    }
}

ok = false;
while (!ok) {
    System.out.print("\n: ");
    kg.setSumme(io.readInteger());
    if (argu_vali.analyse(kg, "sum") == 0) {
        ok = true;
    }
}

k.add_credit(kg);
```

my class Client:

```
class Client{
     String name;

     @t_list_Check
     private ArrayList <truster> t_list= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

my class truster:

```
class Truster{
     String name;

     @Min(0)
     int sum;
}
```

my own ValidatorClass for t_list:

```
public class t_list_Validator implements ConstraintValidator<t_list_Check, Collection> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(t_list_Check a) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Collection kg_list, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
        Object[] objects = kg_list.toArray();

        if (objects.length < 1) {
            return true;
        }

        String new_name = objects[objects.length-1].toString(); //<---need here the
                                                                //right input from above
        for (Object o : kg_list) {
            if (new_name.equals(o.toString())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My problem is now, that I just get the right name for the first element in `t_list`. For the second input for my trusters (`kg.setName(io.readString());`) I receive  from `objects[objects.length-1].toString()` in my `ownValidator` just the last element from `t_list` not the actual element.

For Example:

- 1.run:
- Input in main: test1
- value new_name in t_list_Validator: test1

...

- 2.run:
- Input in main: test 2
- value new_name in t_list_Validator: test1 // need here the actual input: "test2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the element to an list, can solve the problem. After validation delete it from list an go on with validation....

```
while (!ok) {
    System.out.print("\n name: ");


    kg.setName(io.readString()); 

    k.add(kg); // add here the element

    if (argu_vali.analyse(k, "mylist") == 0) {
        ok = true;

    }
    k.remove(k.getList().size()-1); //delete the element and go on with validation
}
```